# how to generate javadocs of my blackberry java files

Tags: blackberry, java-me, javadoc

I have developed one blackberry simple application and wants to generate javadocs of my source code. How to generate javadocs of my java file?

Comment: Blackberry Java source files are no different from normal Java source files (except that they use different libraries), so any normal JavaDoc tutorial will help.

Comment: What IDE are you using? this may help by generating templates for you ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about blackberry, but if they are (at least syntactically) normal Java source files, you can use this command:

```
javadoc -d outputdir -sourcepath src  my.first.package my.second.package ...
```

Have a look at the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) documentation for more options. It might be that you have to add the blackberry library jar files with `-classpath`.